# adding or removing endforeach; throws error!

Tags: php, loop

This is my code, where i keep getting either error: unexpected endforeach; if endforeach is used or unexpected end of file if i don't use endforeach; It's driving me crazy!!

```
<ul id="portfolio-filter">
    <?php
    $k=0;
    $services = array('all', 'marketing', 'SEO', 'web-design', 'web-development',                           'wordpress'); 
    foreach($services as $key) : ?>                     
    <li class="<?php if($k==0) { ?> active <?php { ?>"><a class="<?php echo $key; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $key; ?></a>/</li>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you pasted your code directly,

The second curly bracket here `<?php if($k==0) { ?> active <?php { ?>` should be a closing one, like this:

`<?php if($k==0) { ?> active <?php } ?>`

There is also a stray slash `</a>/</li>` - should be - `</a></li>` - but that shouldn't cause any PHP errors.

Comment: Oh, wow, i guess i am tired!! but the second slash is a separator :) not a mistake.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your full code

```
<ul id="portfolio-filter">
<?php
$k=0;
$services = array('all', 'marketing', 'SEO', 'web-design', 'web-development', 'wordpress'); 
foreach($services as $key) : ?>                     
<li class="<?php if($k==0) { echo "active"; } ?>"><a class="<?php echo $key; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $key; ?></a>/</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```